# GoogleTest: Accessing GetParam in SetUp if the test is non-parameterised

Tags: googletest

I have a SetUp method that checks GetParam() value. Something like:

```
void Tests::SetUp() {
    if (GetParam().data == x) {
        do_something;
    }
}
```

However, some of my tests are P_TESTs, and some are F_TESTs. The F_TESTs do not have a parameter, so I get a segmentation fault when SetUp is called for these tests, as GetParam().data cannot be read!

Is there a way to check that the test has a parameter from inside of the SetUp method?

Thanks.

Comment: Just found it:

// is a parameterised test    
if (::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->current_test_info()->value_param()) 
:)

Comment: Then you should post this as an answer and accept it.